# Issue with cookie removing character

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have created a standard cookie that will remember the user name, then show that name if they visit that page again. For some strange reason, on refresh it removes a character from the name.

I cant work out why this is happening.

Has anyone got any ideas why this could be happening?

You can see an example here:- https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/CGI/portal/test/Untitled-2.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.3/js.cookie.js"></script>

<p>My name is <span class="input-border"></span><input type="text" class="form-control yourfirstname yourfirstname-input" name="yourfirstname" placeholder="yourfirstname" id="yourfirstname" required=""></p><script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var name = Cookies.get('_yourname');
    
    if (name) {
        $('#yourfirstname').val(name);
    }
    
    $('#yourfirstname').keydown(function(){
        var inputName = $('#yourfirstname').val();
        Cookies.set('_yourname', inputName);
    })
});</script>
```

Comment: You're missing the `</head>` and `<body>` `</body>` tags. Try moving the code in between the body tags

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks @Reyno